# Server SSD read speed

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, performance, raid, hp-proliant

We have a hp proliant DL580 Gen10 with

- 5x12Gb/s ssd
- 2x6Gb/s ssd

I put the 2x6Gb/s ssd in raid1 to install esxi.
How do I configure the 5x12Gb/s ssd for max read performance? i.e. the main workload of the 4-10 windows vms is reading large chunks of sequential data and disk read i/o is the bottleneck I want to minimize. (I wouldn't mind parity if the perf hit is less than 10%)

I tested the speed from a linux vm with dd and the read speed from a single disk was 829 MB/s.
The speed from a 4x12GB/s raid0 though, was only  781 MB/s.

Also, why don't I get higher speeds? Where does the 12GB/s come from? How does parallelism affect performance?

Comment: Where did you read the 12GB/second speed from? A webpage / product info somewhere? What exactly did they advertise, any fine print?

Comment: hmm, this should be it's 12Gb/s, so 12GB/8

Comment: It’s probably a SAS 12 GBit/s SSD. That doesn’t mean it can actually reach this speed, of course.

Comment: To identify possible bottlenecks, more information is required: How are the drives connected to the system? What SAS/RAID controller (if any) are you using? What is the exact make and model of all drives? What is the exact configuration if your server?